# How many bytes/KB per tweet?

Tags: string, memory

I have been reading a lot of SO posts and [external blogs](https://janetpanic.com/how-many-bytes-is-a-twitter-post/). Something that is confusing me is without going in too deep into breakup of UTF8 : Does each character mean 2 bytes or 4 bytes? I have seen BOTH being mentioned. Given the CURRENT twitter limit of 280 characters, is this the right calculation ?

```
For A-z0-9 We use 1 byte
    280 * 1 = 280 bytes
```

Comment: UTF8 is *variable-width* - each character can be 1 to 4 bytes, depending on the exact character

Comment: true - but assumung A-z0-9 is that 4 bytes for UTF8 ?

Comment: UTF8 is compatible with ASCII characters, so those all use 1 byte each

Comment: Updated the answer - so 280 bytes is the correct calculation for this?

Comment: Or 281 if it uses a C-style null-terminator (depending on which programming language you use or how the data is stored). And that is of course assuming that only ASCII characters are being used, no characters that are encoded into more than one byte